# How to plot a shape under timesamps in an array when previous bar's close == timestamp

Tags: arrays, plot, pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'd like to plot a shape under the bars of each timestamp in the FOMC array. Logic is when previous bar close == timestamp date/time, then plotshape under that bar. The code below just plots a shape under the current bar.

The idea is to get a boolean output when a previous bar close == timestamps in the array

```
//@version=5

indicator('FOMC TEST', overlay=true)

// Settings
show_fomc_announcement = input.bool(defval = true, title = " FOMC Press Conference", inline = "FOMC Press Conference", group="Settings")
color_fomc_announcement = input.color(color.new(color.blue, 0), title = "Color", inline="FOMC Press Conference", group="Settings")

// FOMC Press Conference

var int[] fomc_announcement_dates = 
  array.from(
   timestamp("27 Jan 2021 14:00:00 EST"),
   timestamp("17 Mar 2021 14:00:00 EDT"),
   timestamp("28 Apr 2021 14:00:00 EDT"),
   timestamp("16 Jun 2021 14:00:00 EDT"),
   timestamp("28 Jul 2021 14:00:00 EDT"),
   timestamp("22 Sep 2021 14:00:00 EDT"),
   timestamp("3 Nov 2021 14:00:00 EDT"),
   timestamp("15 Dec 2021 14:00:00 EDT"),
   timestamp("26 Jan 2022 14:00:00 EDT"),
   timestamp("16 Mar 2022 14:00:00 EDT"),
   timestamp("4 May 2022 14:00:00 EDT"),
   timestamp("15 Jun 2022 14:00:00 EDT"),
   timestamp("27 Jul 2022 14:00:00 EDT"),
   timestamp("21 Sep 2022 14:00:00 EDT"),
   timestamp("2 Nov 2022 14:00:00 EDT"),
   timestamp("14 Dec 2022 14:00:00 EST"),
   timestamp("1 Feb 2023 14:00:00 EST"),
   timestamp("22 March 2023 14:00:00 EDT"),
   timestamp("3 May 2023 14:00:00 EDT"),
   timestamp("14 June 2023 14:00:00 EDT"),
   timestamp("26 July 2023 14:00:00 EDT"),
   timestamp("20 Sept 2023 14:00:00 EDT"),
   timestamp("1 Nov 2023 14:00:00 EDT"),
   timestamp("13 Dec 2023 14:00:00 EST")   
   )

getUnixTime(_eventArr, _index) => 
    switch 
        timeframe.isdaily => array.get(_eventArr, _index) - timeframe.multiplier*86400000 // -n day(s)
        timeframe.isweekly => array.get(_eventArr, _index) - timeframe.multiplier*604800000 // -n week(s)
        timeframe.ismonthly => array.get(_eventArr, _index) - timeframe.multiplier*2592000000 // -n month(s)
        timeframe.isminutes and timeframe.multiplier > 59 => array.get(_eventArr, _index) - timeframe.multiplier*60000 // -n minute(s)
        => array.get(_eventArr, _index)

// Process and draw the dates

var fomc_announcement_date = 0

if barstate.islastconfirmedhistory
            
    if show_fomc_announcement
        y = 0
        while y < array.size(fomc_announcement_dates)
            fomc_announcement_date := getUnixTime(fomc_announcement_dates, y)
            line.new(x1=fomc_announcement_date, y1=high, x2=fomc_announcement_date, y2=low, extend=extend.both, color=color_fomc_announcement, width=1, xloc=xloc.bar_time, style = line.style_dotted)
            y += 1 

// Check if the current bar's close time matches any FOMC timestamp
is_fomc_timestamp() =>
    _found = false
    for i = 0 to array.size(fomc_announcement_dates) - 1
        if barstate.islastconfirmedhistory and barstate.ishistory
            if array.get(fomc_announcement_dates, i) == timenow
                _found := true
                break
    _found

shape = is_fomc_timestamp()

plotshape(shape, style=shape.xcross, color = color.new(color.green,50), location = location.bottom, size = size.huge)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXANo.png)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
indicator('FOMC TEST', overlay=true)

// Settings
show_fomc_announcement = input.bool(defval = true, title = " FOMC Press Conference", inline = "FOMC Press Conference", group="Settings")
color_fomc_announcement = input.color(color.new(color.blue, 50), title = "Color", inline="FOMC Press Conference", group="Settings")

// FOMC Press Conference

var int[] fomc_announcement_dates = 
  array.from(
   timestamp("27 Jan 2021 14:00:00 EST"),
   timestamp("17 Mar 2021 14:00:00 EDT"),
   timestamp("28 Apr 2021 14:00:00 EDT"),
   timestamp("16 Jun 2021 14:00:00 EDT"),
   timestamp("28 Jul 2021 14:00:00 EDT"),
   timestamp("22 Sep 2021 14:00:00 EDT"),
   timestamp("3 Nov 2021 14:00:00 EDT"),
   timestamp("15 Dec 2021 14:00:00 EDT"),
   timestamp("26 Jan 2022 14:00:00 EDT"),
   timestamp("16 Mar 2022 14:00:00 EDT"),
   timestamp("4 May 2022 14:00:00 EDT"),
   timestamp("15 Jun 2022 14:00:00 EDT"),
   timestamp("27 Jul 2022 14:00:00 EDT"),
   timestamp("21 Sep 2022 14:00:00 EDT"),
   timestamp("2 Nov 2022 14:00:00 EDT"),
   timestamp("14 Dec 2022 14:00:00 EST"),
   timestamp("1 Feb 2023 14:00:00 EST"),
   timestamp("22 March 2023 14:00:00 EDT"),
   timestamp("3 May 2023 14:00:00 EDT"),
   timestamp("14 June 2023 14:00:00 EDT"),
   timestamp("26 July 2023 14:00:00 EDT"),
   timestamp("20 Sept 2023 14:00:00 EDT"),
   timestamp("1 Nov 2023 14:00:00 EDT"),
   timestamp("13 Dec 2023 14:00:00 EST")   
   )


shouldAnchorArray(dates, col) =>
    var announcement_date = 0
    anchored = false
    for i = 0 to array.size(dates)-1
        announcement_date := array.get(dates,i) 
        line.new(x1=announcement_date, y1=high, x2=announcement_date, y2=low, extend=extend.both, color=col, width=1, xloc=xloc.bar_time, style = line.style_dotted)

    
        shouldAnchor = array.get(dates,i) > time[1] and array.get(dates,i) <= time

        if shouldAnchor
        
            anchored := true
            break
    
    anchored
    
fomcAnchor = shouldAnchorArray(fomc_announcement_dates, color_fomc_announcement)

plotshape(fomcAnchor, style=shape.xcross, color = color.new(color.yellow,50), location = location.bottom, size = size.huge)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).